# Different results in GUI vs terminal

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I have one file that includes a class definition and another that imports that module. When I run the latter, it appears to not know that I edited the other file and continues to give me the same error.  However, when I run it in a Canopy Terminal, it works as desired.  Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Quite hard (and near impossible) without providing any *context/source* code.

Comment: seems like the .pyc doesn't get updated when updating the .py file. Weird.

Comment: Several users objected to your question as unclear, and put it on hold. IMO the sequence of events that you described was actually fairly clear, and their objections mostly just reflect unfamiliarity with the Canopy IDE. Nonetheless,  it would be a good exercise and a good service to the community if you tried to improve your question, now that you understand the answer, so that others with similar issues would be more likely to find it when searching. For example, it's not about GUI vs terminal, but about ipython vs plain python (easy to say in retrospect!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because IPython keeps your kernel process running, so the lower-level module remains imported (specifically it remains listed in `sys.modules`) so it is not re-imported when you re-run your main script. (Just as it would not be re-imported if you issued the `import` command twice in a row.) While perhaps counterintuitive at first, this is a deliberate feature. For detail, see https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart

Comment: Thank you!  That is extremely helpful!